# 'filesystem "/boot" has the wrong type for an EFI System Partition'

Tags: linux, arch-linux, parted

I get this error when  i run `bootctl install` in chroot

```
filesystem "/boot" has the wrong type for an EFI System Partition
```

I searched online and someone else had this problem and his solution was he was missing a boot flag.

When i type "print" in `parted` to see my partitions it shows the flag for my /boot partition is "msftdata" is this what i am supposed to change? and how?

I am installing it on my ASUS laptop (uefi)

Answer (score 2):

In `parted`, the flags for an ESP partition should be `boot` and `esp`, not `msftdata`.

When using GPT partitioning with `parted`, the `boot` flag is just an alias for `esp` flag.

`parted` presents the GPT partition type GUIDs as "flags". This is a bit limiting, since there are [a lot of GPT partition types defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) and only a few of those are accessible as flags in `parted`. It is also confusing, as you might think you can apply multiple flags at the same time, but in reality, a GPT partition can have only one type GUID at any time. It is not immediately obvious in `parted` that the `esp` and `msftdata` flags are mutually exclusive, but in fact they are exactly that.

In `gdisk`, the GPT partition types are presented as short codes, like `ef00` as mentioned by FireFaced. But those codes are specific to the `gdisk` tool: they mean nothing at all in `parted` or in any other GPT partitioning tool.

If you use `parted`, remove the `msftdata` flag from your `/boot` partition and apply the `esp` flag instead. The `boot` flag should then appear automatically.

The requirements for UEFI boot from a GPT partitioned disk are:

- the presence of an ESP partition with the proper partition type GUID (= the `esp` flag in `parted`)
- a filesystem in the ESP partition that is supported by the system firmware (FAT32 is the filesystem type required by the UEFI standard, but the firmware can support other types too; for example, in Apple systems, the ESP partition can have a HFS+ filesystem.)
- and either a configured UEFI boot variable, or a bootloader file in the architecture-dependent fallback path: for 64-bit x86 systems, the fallback path is `\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi` as expressed in FAT32 native style.

Comment: To have the actual command: execute `parted /dev/sdX set 1 esp` *(substitute `/dev/sdX` with device name and `1` with the partition number)*.

Answer (score 0):

The partition's GUID should be `ef00`, and the file system should be FAT32. There's no need for any flags, if /boot matches those requirements.

Comment: when i made the partitions i set it to ef00 and i formatted it to FAT32 but i still get this error, what should i do?

Comment: Try `mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdXY`, but replacing X with your drive, and Y with the ESP (Efi System Partition)

Comment: i did that already, i also tried again now and same error

Comment: @Hova Try `efivar -l`

Comment: what am i supposed to see after running that?

Comment: @Hova A long output with a bunch of "gibberish"

Comment: yeah thats what i got

Comment: @Hova Would you be able to destroy the partition table and remake it without losing sensitive data? That seems like the only option now.

Comment: i'm not sure, i've been following the arch [beginners guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide) on the wiki and im at the step where i have to install the bootloader. the drive was clean before i started this installation. this is my second time attemping to install, last time i ran into the same issue so i decided to start from scratch

Comment: Hmm. I would recommend doing the regular installation guide, it generally works better.

Comment: @Hova Sadly though, we can't have an extended conversation because you don't have enough rep for chat.

Comment: Probably delete your email comment, go to #archlinux on Freenode

Comment: are you on the "+q $~a." channel? that is the main channel from the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IRC_channel#.23archlinux_-_The_official_support_channel)

Comment: @Hova ? I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: im not sure either, never used freenode lol, do you know any other place we can talk?

Comment: webchat.freenode.net Set your nick as Hova, and join #archlinux-unregistered, then talk.

Comment: her are you still there?

Comment: @Hova I'm still here